# recognice with javascript number inside of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find if there is any way by Javascript / jQuery from a determine whether the image is an image number.

The reality is that I have this that is generated dynamically so the numbers change position.

[image]

This image corresponds to this code more or less:

```
<div id="a_pin1_1" class="digit d-0"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_1" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '0');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_2" class="digit d-1"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_2" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '1');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_3" class="digit d-2"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_3" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '2');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_4" class="digit d-3"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_4" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '3');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_5" class="digit d-4"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_5" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '4');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_6" class="digit d-5"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_6" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '5');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_7" class="digit d-6"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_7" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '6');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_8" class="digit d-7"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_8" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '7');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_9" class="digit d-8"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_9" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '8');return false;"></div>
<div id="a_pin1_10" class="digit d-9"><img alt="" id="img_pin1_10" class="pin-digit" src="./PinpadIconsHandler.ashx?idSs=97f8044b-6304-4ca1-9ac1-2d5732817f0c&amp;c=1&amp;t=20160219131147" onclick="Arquia.insertPinPadDigit2('pin1', '9');return false;"></div>
```

Any idea to recognize number showing the image using Javascript / jQuery?

A greeting and thanks for the help

Comment: What could be the purpose of it??? I can imagine but i prefer to ask...

Comment: Why not attach a `data-number` attribute to the element and inspect that instead. I don't think image recognition is what you really want here, but without knowing why you want to do it it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Finally the solution I've been given to do ocr image and thereby get the numbers are sorted as in the picture. So using the position of the numbers in the image, I get to create a map that corresponds to each number button.
As the purpose is to integrate bank accounting movements in an application.